# Json decoding in Android

Tags: android, json

I am facing an difficulty in decoding an json string. Below is my json string:

```
{
    "udeals":"[{\"vName\":\"bussinessname3\",\"vAddress\":\"address3\",\"vState\":\"Kerala\",\"vZip\":\"232\",\"vCountry\":\"Algeria\",\"id\":\"3\",\"dealCategoryID\":\"2\",\"dealCaption\":\"deal3\",\"dealurl\":\"http:\\/\\/192.168.0.8\\/ppppp\\/deals\\/deal3-3\\/\",\"dealImage\":\"http:\\/\\/192.168.0.8\\/ppppp\\/images\\/deals\\/thumb390x256\\/Duizl1.jpg\",\"dealPrice\":\"50.00\",\"dealCost\":\"100.00\",\"dealSave\":-50,\"dealOfferRate\":\"50.00\",\"jsDeadLine\":{\"seconds\":0,\"minutes\":0,\"hours\":0,\"mday\":5,\"wday\":3,\"mon\":1,\"year\":2011,\"yday\":4,\"weekday\":\"Wednesday\",\"month\":\"January\",\"0\":1294165800},\"unlockedStamp\":{\"seconds\":53,\"minutes\":56,\"hours\":18,\"mday\":5,\"wday\":3,\"mon\":1,\"year\":2011,\"yday\":4,\"weekday\":\"Wednesday\",\"month\":\"January\",\"0\":1294234013},\"description\":\"Google URL Shortener at goo.gl is used by Google products to create short URLs that can be easily shared, tweeted, or emailed to friends.\"},{\"vName\":\"bussinessname20010\",\"vAddress\":\"address20010\",\"vState\":\"Kerala\",\"vZip\":\"232\",\"vCountry\":\"Argentina\",\"id\":\"20010\",\"dealCategoryID\":\"2\",\"dealCaption\":\"deal20010\",\"dealurl\":\"http:\\/\\/192.168.0.8\\/ppppp\\/deals\\/deal20010-20010\\/\",\"dealImage\":\"http:\\/\\/192.168.0.8\\/ppppp\\/images\\/deals\\/thumb390x256\\/oCcfTj.jpg\",\"dealPrice\":\"50.00\",\"dealCost\":\"100.00\",\"dealSave\":-50,\"dealOfferRate\":\"50.00\",\"jsDeadLine\":{\"seconds\":0,\"minutes\":0,\"hours\":0,\"mday\":28,\"wday\":2,\"mon\":12,\"year\":2010,\"yday\":361,\"weekday\":\"Tuesday\",\"month\":\"December\",\"0\":1293474600},\"unlockedStamp\":{\"seconds\":53,\"minutes\":56,\"hours\":18,\"mday\":5,\"wday\":3,\"mon\":1,\"year\":2011,\"yday\":4,\"weekday\":\"Wednesday\",\"month\":\"January\",\"0\":1294234013},\"description\":\"this is\"}]"
}
```

Can any one please give me an solution for how to parse this in Android...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this json can be parse using the following code.

```
str="<The Json>"
try {
                    JSONObject jObject=new JSONObject(str);
                    JSONArray menuObject = new JSONArray(jObject.getString("udeals"));

                    for (int i = 0; i<menuObject.length(); i++) {
                        System.out.println("length="+menuObject.length());
                        System.out.println("vName="+menuObject.getJSONObject(i)
                                .getString("vName"));
                        System.out.println("vAddress="+menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                                "vAddress"));
                        System.out.println("vState="+menuObject.getJSONObject(i)
                                .getString("vState"));
                        System.out.println("vZip="+menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                                "vZip"));
                        System.out.println("vCountry="+menuObject.getJSONObject(i)
                                .getString("vCountry"));
                        System.out.println("dealCategoryID="+menuObject.getJSONObject(i)
                                .getString("dealCategoryID"));
                        System.out.println("dealCaption="+menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                                "dealCaption"));
                        System.out.println("dealImage="+menuObject.getJSONObject(i)
                                .getString("dealImage"));
                        System.out.println("dealPrice="+menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                                "dealPrice"));
                        System.out.println("dealCost="+menuObject.getJSONObject(i)
                                .getString("dealCost"));
                        System.out.println("dealSave="+menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                                "dealSave"));
                        System.out.println("dealOfferRate="+menuObject.getJSONObject(i)
                                .getString("dealOfferRate"));
                        System.out.println("jsDeadLine="+menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                                "jsDeadLine"));
                        jsDeadLine=menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getString("jsDeadLine");
                        JSONObject deadLine= new JSONObject(jsDeadLine);
                        String seconds = deadLine.getString("seconds");
                        String minutes = deadLine.getString("minutes");
                        String hours = deadLine.getString("hours");
                        String mday = deadLine.getString("mday");
                        String wday = deadLine.getString("wday");
                        String mon = deadLine.getString("mon");
                        String year = deadLine.getString("year");
                        String yday = deadLine.getString("yday");
                        String weekday = deadLine.getString("weekday");
                        String month = deadLine.getString("month");
                        System.out.println("seconds:"+seconds);
                        System.out.println("minutes:"+minutes);
                        System.out.println("hours:"+hours);



                        System.out.println("unlockedStamp="+menuObject.getJSONObject(i)
                                .getString("unlockedStamp"));

                        unlockedStamp=menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getString("unlockedStamp");
                        JSONObject unlocked= new JSONObject(unlockedStamp);
                        String unlockedseconds = unlocked.getString("seconds");
                        String unlockedminutes = unlocked.getString("minutes");
                        String unlockedhours = unlocked.getString("hours");
                        String unlockedmday = unlocked.getString("mday");
                        String unlockedwday = unlocked.getString("wday");
                        String unlockedmon = unlocked.getString("mon");
                        String unlockedyear = unlocked.getString("year");
                        String unlockedyday = unlocked.getString("yday");
                        String unlockedweekday = unlocked.getString("weekday");
                        String unlockedmonth = unlocked.getString("month");
                        System.out.println("unlockedseconds:"+unlockedseconds);
                        System.out.println("unlockedminutes:"+unlockedminutes);
                        System.out.println("unlockedhours:"+unlockedhours);


                        System.out.println("description="+menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                                "description"));
                        System.out.println("id="+menuObject.getJSONObject(i)
                                .getString("id"));
                        System.out.println("dealurl="+menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                                "dealurl"));
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }




    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(yourstring);
JSONArray jsa = json.getJSONArray("udeals");
....
```

It's really easy : http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: I notice that udeals isn't in fact an array, but a string (surrounded in double quotes). Would this still work? This could be where basil is experiencing his problem... To fix it, he'd have to say: JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(yourstring); JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(json.getString("udeals")); Right?