# how to decode json in android

Tags: android, json

this is my json data

```
 [{"FeedbackId":"1","Phoneid":"9774d56d682e549c","feedbackdate":"2011\/9 \/24","GuestName":"sdf","Address":"sdf","Phone":"456","Email":"sdf","suggestion":"sdf","grievances":"sdf","visitAgain":"0","purposeofvisit":"sdf","flag":"1"},{"FeedbackId":"2","Phoneid":"9774d56d682e549c","feedbackdate":"","GuestName":"sdf","Address":"sdf","Phone":"456","Email":"sdf","suggestion":"sdf","grievances":"sdf","visitAgain":"0","purposeofvisit":"sdf","flag":"1"},{"FeedbackId":"3","Phoneid":"9774d56d682e549c","feedbackdate":"","GuestName":"sdf","Address":"sdf","Phone":"456","Email":"sdf","suggestion":"sdf","grievances":"sdf","visitAgain":"0","purposeofvisit":"sdf","flag":"1"},{"FeedbackId":"4","Phoneid":"9774d56d682e549c","feedbackdate":"2011\/9 \/24","GuestName":"sdf","Address":"dsf","Phone":"456","Email":"sdf","suggestion":"sf","grievances":"sdf","visitAgain":"0","purposeofvisit":"sdf","flag":"1"},{"FeedbackId":"5","Phoneid":"9774d56d682e549c","feedbackdate":"2011\/9 \/24","GuestName":"sdf","Address":"dsf","Phone":"456","Email":"sdf","suggestion":"sf","grievances":"sdf","visitAgain":"0","purposeofvisit":"sdf","flag":"1"},{"FeedbackId":"6","Phoneid":"9774d56d682e549c","feedbackdate":"","GuestName":"xcv","Address":"xcv","Phone":"89","Email":"xcv","suggestion":"xcv","grievances":"xcv","visitAgain":"1","purposeofvisit":"","flag":"1"},{"FeedbackId":"7","Phoneid":"9774d56d682e549c","feedbackdate":"","GuestName":"gfhj","Address":"ghj6678","Phone":"678","Email":"ghjgh","suggestion":"678fgh","grievances":"fgh","visitAgain":"0","purposeofvisit":"sdf","flag":"1"}]
```

how to decode this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Json decoding in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604657/json-decoding-in-android)

Comment: but i have all different data.how to decode.i see link but i cant understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to decode using the [org.json](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) package. From [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html):

```
String json = "{"
         + "  \"query\": \"Pizza\", "
         + "  \"locations\": [ 94043, 90210 ] "
         + "}";

 JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(json).nextValue();
 String query = object.getString("query");
 JSONArray locations = object.getJSONArray("locations");
```

Just use your own JSON instead of theirs.

Comment: You can also use the JSONObject(String) constructor: `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);`