# Google Places API - Decoding Json at the Android End

Tags: java, android, json, google-places-api

I'm fairly new to dealing with json, currently working with Google Places API to get restaurant details. I've already tried to decode it by followig articles such as

- [how to decode json in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551305/how-to-decode-json-in-android)

but it has been of no use as my json string is quite complex as far as my understanding is concerned

I'm getting json via Volley API using this particular function

```
public String getVolleyURL() {
        String query = null;
//            query = SEARCH_QUERY + "&location=" + lat + "," + lon + "&radius=" + radius;
            query = "&location=" + lat  + "," +longg + "&radius=" + radius;

        query = SEARCH_URL + query + "&key=" + GOOGLE_PLACE_KEY;
        Log.wtf(TAG, "Volley_URL = " + query);
        return query;
    }
```

which returns the following Json string

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {
         "formatted_address" : "Metropolitan Life North Building, 11 Madison Ave, New York, NY 10010, Verenigde Staten",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.74169,
               "lng" : -73.9872068
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.74190884999999,
                  "lng" : -73.98716930000001
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.74161705,
                  "lng" : -73.98731529999999
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "f758e0d7f68c659682afdb4b1c0749e7d3623839",
         "name" : "Eleven Madison Park",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 1200,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102127816559576392189/photos\"\u003eTammy Liu\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CoQBdwAAACwNCAsIpt6Li3P49bVZfSX8yDOA3QTsPsgc52jYRliBNBEqboYcE409Wf-ZYIae__HbKvaW1Xed-lnKjr0dus2Gbnn1Y8PTH_7HX89aiDo4lTASyuU8N7DxHndhiAXPqY-ZKozOzLcSYA7tP50_-caFILD36WpSQJIEWSPu3cgzEhCQ7c2ltmabHZsR88s-gc8kGhShA5LDudy3ZvcDAjalj9yn_KR7bw",
               "width" : 1800
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJEWbXz6ZZwokRLKmKrtPfVFY",
         "price_level" : 4,
         "rating" : 4.5,
         "reference" : "CnRmAAAAWyhPb38cmZ765RA05cPPZkYqZbRGtDOOQi8d5yNuwCrvezX4liYo6DFNOdr8c-v2wwwnD9OqODteeO9oto9wNGI3F0ORvjKYCAwaNwGOMc2x8JYUljND4XmG41s0d44OXWxzloUQgRubjuFEDpTkhBIQAeucZk-7vCj6xP76Mkwt2RoUMaR7pkhrawYFttRUBIYellvYoJc",
         "types" : [ "restaurant", "bar", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Any sort of help would REALLY be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Use API like gson to parse the json and get the required values.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)? JSON is a very common, standard format so there are tons of resources for interfacing with them.  The "rules" of JSONs can be seen [here](http://www.json.org/).

Answer (score 0):

suppose if u want to decode `formatted address` from json response try this:

Things to note: formatted address address comes under "results" key in your json response

JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(query);

JSONObject sys  = reader.getJSONObject("results");

address = sys.getString("formatted_address");

so finally address will have value "Metropolitan Life North Building, 11 Madison Ave"

Answer (score 0):

This code should help you to parse data from google places api. **happy code !**

```
 String reference;
 String vicinity;
 String rating;
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray data = reader.getJSONArray("results");           
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
JSONObject place = (JSONObject) data.get(i);
 String idplace = place.getString("id");
 String name = place.getString("name");
 Double lat = place.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lat");
  Double lng = place.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getDouble("lng");
 if(place.has("photos")) {
    reference = place.getJSONArray("photos").getJSONObject(0).getString("photo_reference");
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            reference =null;
                        }
                        if(place.has("vicinity")) {
                            //it has it, do appropriate processing
                             vicinity = place.getString("vicinity");
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            vicinity =null;
                        }

                        if(place.has("rating")) {
                            //it has it, do appropriate processing
                            rating = String.valueOf(place.getDouble("rating"));
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            rating =null;
                        }
                        // String vicinity = place.getString("vicinity");
                        //String rating = String.valueOf(place.getDouble("rating"));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
```