# Convert Json array intro String

Tags: android, json

I have a result from PHP as JSONObject

```
{"Requests":[{"fromid":"theDude"},{"fromid":"vishaliopeepak@gmail.com"}],"success":1}
```

I want to get the from ids intro String array in **Android**?. I have seen other examples but im unable to get it right.

Comment: how is the response 2D-array

Comment: ok i found an answer in another post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604657/json-decoding-in-android) . But im unable to delete this question

Comment: i unmarked it and tried but it still does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
String response = "{'Requests':[{'fromid':'theDude'},{'fromid':'vishaliopeepak@gmail.com'}],'success':1}";
    JSONObject obj;
    try {
        obj = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray jarray = obj.getJSONArray("Requests");
        String success = obj.getString("success");
        if (success.equals("1")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject Jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                if(Jobj.has("fromid"))
                Log.i("fromid", Jobj.getString("fromid") + "fromid");

            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```